# email doesn't work in Cloudflare DNS

Tags: cloudflare

I wanted try to Cloudflare, changed my DNS and checked mx and mail values. But mail still doesn't work.

I wonder also what is free plan of Cloudflare protects my Website from?

Answer (score 1):

After moving your website over to CloudFlare you must set up what are called MX DNS Records. These are bits of information that tell email solutions like gmail where to send email when your domain is used.

To setup an MX record do the following:

1. **N**avigate to the DNS panel in your CloudFlare control panel
2. **S**elect the record type as MX from the dropdown box: [image: Selecting MX]
3. **A**s we are creating MX records that allow emails to @example.com be received, set the name as @. If you are using an external email provider enter their domain address instead here:[image: Selecting Domain to create MX record under]
4. **C**licking the next field will open up a box in which two things are set - the server, and the priority of this server. Type in the address of the mail server - in our example this will be mx1.mail.com. Also select the priority that you are advised to set - this server will have have the priority of 10: [image: Setting Mail Priority]
5. **C**lick save. Unless specifically asked by your email provider to set a certain TTL, leave “Automatic TTL” selected. Finally click “Add Record”. Your first MX record will now be saved and added to the list of your DNS records:[image: Leaving TTL alone]
   ([source](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218069617-How-do-I-add-or-edit-mail-or-MX-records-))

Answer (score 0):

To compare what protection features you get with the different CloudFlare plans, check out the table at the bottom of https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/

As you probably know, changes in MX values may take 24hrs to propagate. In your case though, if you just changed to the CloudFlare name servers and the MX servers were unchanged, I wouldn't expect there to be any issue with your mail delivery.

> But mail still doesn't work.

Can you give more details?

Answer (score 0):

i just click on Mail DNS and make cloud grey, now emails are working.
Change your MAIL's proxy status to DNS Only ( grey cloud) and your email will start working

Answer (score 0):

When using CloudFlare, check a few things to make sure your email is working:

**1.** Is your email working in webmail? If yes, there's probably a CloudFlare DNS setting that needs adjusting.

**2.** In CloudFlare make sure there is a mail A-record (not CNAME) pointing to the mailserver IP with a grey cloud (so not proxied through CloudFlare).

If there is a CNAME record instead, delete that and add a new A-record, pointing to your server. The image below shows an example setup. in the 'Content' column you would have your server IP-address instead of the example 11.22.33.44 IP-address.

[image: Example CloudFlare A-record for mail]

Also see https://community.cloudflare.com/t/email-not-working-since-switching-on-cloudflare/41068/3 for more information.

**3.** Check the SSL settings (doesn't necessarily have to do with email, but good to make sure it's correct too)

If the site uses its own SSL certificate, like through Let's Encrypt, then in Cloudflare SSL should *not* be set to flexible. Set it to full or strict instead.