# After correcting DNS on cloudflare, hosted email continues to fail

Tags: email, dns, cloudflare

- Research [a]: [Cloudflare's help page][1]
- Research [b]:[Stackover flow conversation on this topic][2]
- Research [c]:[hosting provider, other than mine, offering troubleshooting from forum  forum][3]

I tried to follow instruction from stack overflow [Research B] regarding MX and cloudflare.   And I just can't seem to make sense of it compared to cloudflare's help page [research A].

History:  email had been working for inboud and outbound from hosting provider (Network Solutions).  I set up cloudflare with automatic recognition of settings.  ~24hrs later only outbound emails were working.   I attempted to follow directsion from Research B, and now 24hr later, I can't log in to email either.

Does any have a before and after example screenshot?

I made screenshots of DNS MX [before][4] and [after][5] (following the stackoverflow [research b] instructions best I could).

1. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168876-My-email-or-mail-stopped-working-What-should-I-do-

   2. [email doesn't work in Cloudflare DNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374074/email-doesnt-work-in-cloudflare-dns)

Comment: 3. http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/community-support/email-troubleshooting/settings-for-email-using-cloudflare
4. https://postimg.org/image/ru3cvei7j/ 
5. https://postimg.org/image/8din8vn3j/

Comment: Apparently, I didn't have enough reputation points to post three more links in the first question

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the following:

1. There is an MX record for the root of your domain @.
2. Where the MX record points, there is a valid A Record for that subdomain. That A Record needs to be "grey clouded" so that it doesn't route through Cloudflare.
3. If you have a webmail login domain (e.g. webmail.domain.com) that DNS record needs to also exist.

Comment: thanks....  I think I have confirmed all you are talking about...[postimg.org/image/8din8vn3j ](What I have)

Answer (score 0):

resolved.:

So using network solutions:

Modify MX record.   the CNAME records (for me) updated correctly.

MX Record: inbound.yourwebsite.com.netsolmail.net

·         Recommended Priority: 10
·         Recommended TTL: 7200

1st CNAME Record: mail.yourwebsite.com.netsolmail.net

·         Alias: mail
·         Recommended TTL: 7200

2nd CNAME Record: smtp.yourwebsite.com.netsolmail.net

·         Alias: smtp
·         Recommended TTL: 7200